# How to add columns to CSV using PHP

Tags: php

I need to add columns to an existing csv file ,but i can't find any solution to the problem.I have used "\t" and chr(9) to create columns but no success so please help me by providing me the right solution if any one can

Comment: can you show your current code?

Comment: file_put_contents("test.csv","\n".$dob[0].chr(9).$city[0].chr(9).$country[0],FILE_APPEND); my code

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this, and have a look at [fgetcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) in the manual

```
<?php
$newCsvData = array();
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = 'New Column';
        $newCsvData[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach ($newCsvData as $line) {
   fputcsv($handle, $line);
}

fclose($handle);

?>
```

Comment: This worked well for me for smaller files, however with bigger files, this is at risk of hitting memory limits with the $newCsvData.

Answer (score -3):

Could you try using `\r\n` instead of `\n` ?