# PHP Append Column to end of the CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I have a CSV file in the php server

Want to Add "h3" at the end and fill the row with data "data3"

here is the structure

```
  H1      H2   (h3)
  XXX     XXX   data3
  xxx     xxx   data3
```

I am trying with the following code for a long time, havent get any luck yet

```
<?php
$newCsvData = array();
if (($handle = fopen("file.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $data[] = 'report_type';
        $newCsvData[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$handle = fopen('test.csv', 'w');

foreach ($newCsvData as $line) {
    fputcsv($handle, $line);
}

fclose($handle);
?>
```

Please advice

Comment: It looks just right to me. Can you please provide an example "file.csv" (the structure you provided seems to be separated by spaces or tabs, but you are parsing by comma seperated values?), and also, state what outcome you currently get (in your test.csv)

Comment: this is almost identical to - [how-to-add-columns-to-csv-using-php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371005/how-to-add-columns-to-csv-using-php)

Comment: *havent get any luck yet*...what does not work? Any error? Undesired results?

Comment: Yes, I move the code into separate file. It work, but it append the whole column with "report_type", is there way change the header and the data separately?

Comment: Please illustrate current undesired result.

Comment: Well, I sort of track it by change the header row afterward. Thanks for your help